# android try to execute php files

Tags: php, android, request

I try to create a little application which execute php file on my server ( host on ovh ).
I have try many script but on my phone i always have this error : 
W/dalvikvm(26780): No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I

So i try with the emulator. At first it was working but now i also have this error.....
I have empty all my class and i still have ...
If anyone know where is the probleme ( i work with eclispe ) or have a good script to execute php files, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class -

```
public class AddQuery extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private String url;
private String jsonResult;
private String qrs;
private String cId;

public AddQuery(Context context, String qrs, String cid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.qrs = qrs;
    this.cId = cid;
    url = "http://" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.url)
            + "/ques.php";
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.setMessage("Retrieving Data..");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.multisoft",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("go", "add"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qrs", qrs));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid", cId));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", prefs.getString("userID", "0")));
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                .toString();
    }

    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("e", "error1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("e", "error2");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String rLine = "";
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            answer.append(rLine);
        }
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error..." + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return answer;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
pd.dismiss();
//do what you want to do here from text apeared from your php and stored in jsonResult
}
```

execute the above class in your main activity like this-

```
new AddQuery(MyActivity.class, "4","23").execute();
```

Comment: url = "http://" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.url)
            + "/ques.php";

It's seems R.String.url could not be used.

Thanks you very much for all the time youn spend for me.

Comment: That was my code, you will have to change according to your code, change MainActivity.class to MainActivity.this and set url to url="http://www.yourdomain.com/your_php_file.php"

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but do you know how i can have the result of ny request in an other class ? I can execute the php file but i can't have the result.
Thank you very much

Comment: Please explain your question more, can't get response from php or somthing else?

Comment: Maybe you have email or something like that, it's could be more easy to chat.